# Excel VBA - Calling Multiple Subs in one Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

The below code works fine if I split the process into 3 separate subs but i am having issues combining this into one process.

Ideally, I would like the code to run and temporarily unlock the 'Sheet', perform the 'Worksheet_Calculate' sub and then lock the 'Sheet' again.

Could someone please assist.

---

```
Private Sub UnprotectAll()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim yourPassword As String
yourPassword = "Test"

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Unprotect Password:=yourPassword
Next sh
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next


Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next

For Each Dependents In Range("G6")
For Each HideDependents In Range("G18:G19")
    If Dependents.Value = 0 Then
        HideDependents.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Dependents.Value >= 1 Then
        HideDependents.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Next
Next

For Each Vehicle In Range("G7")
For Each HideVehicle In Range("G45:G48")
    If Vehicle.Value = 0 Then
        HideVehicle.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Vehicle.Value >= 1 Then
        HideVehicle.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Next
Next

For Each Joint In Range("G9")
For Each HideJoint In Range("I14:J65")
    If Joint.Value = 0 Then
        HideJoint.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Joint.Value = 1 Then
        HideJoint.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
Next
Next
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Private Sub ProtectAll()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim yourPassword As String
yourPassword = "Test"

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Protect Password:=yourPassword
Next sh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There a number of other efficiencies that could be gained but this is one way to combine, wraps the each sheet loop around the whole thing.

```
Private Sub Combine()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim yourPassword As String
yourPassword = "Test"

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Unprotect Password:=yourPassword

Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next

For Each Dependents In Range("G6")
For Each HideDependents In Range("G18:G19")
    If Dependents.Value = 0 Then
        HideDependents.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Dependents.Value >= 1 Then
        HideDependents.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Next
Next

For Each Vehicle In Range("G7")
For Each HideVehicle In Range("G45:G48")
    If Vehicle.Value = 0 Then
        HideVehicle.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Vehicle.Value >= 1 Then
        HideVehicle.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Next
Next

For Each Joint In Range("G9")
For Each HideJoint In Range("I14:J65")
    If Joint.Value = 0 Then
        HideJoint.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Joint.Value = 1 Then
        HideJoint.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
Next
Next

On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
    sh.Protect Password:=yourPassword

Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it works however is there any way of the script automatically running through the process when 'G6:G9' changes as i currently have to run the command manually in order for the changes to take place.

Comment: Add the following to the worksheet which you want to automatically update/monitor for changes.

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G6:G9")) Is Nothing Then
        Call combine
    End If
End Sub